# Como imprimir vários textarea (usados com o TinyMCE), que são gravados em BLOB, num unico PDF?

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce-4

Tenho vários textarea (mais de 20), em páginas diferentes do PHP e utilizo o TinyMCE como editor de todos esses textarea. Todos são gravados no MySQL como BLOB, uma vez que todos os textarea permitem texto e imagem, e muitos caracteres em cada. Meu problema: não consigo imprimir todos os textarea num único arquivo PDF (uso o FPDF, mas já tentei com html2pdf e tb não funfou). Quando chamo os campos gravados como BLOB através de um SELECT, o texto até que imprime (com alguns pequenos erros de acentuação/ç, conforme abaixo), mas as imagens não imprime de jeito algum, apenas o seguinte sai no PDF no lugar da imagem:

`<img title="foto.jpg" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk........>`

E no lugar de palavras, tais como "CONCEITUAÇÃO", imprime:

`CONCEITUA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O`

Neste último caso, já tentei usar `utf8_decode` e `htmlspecialchars_decode`, mas não adiantou. No caso da imagem, não tenho nem ideia de como resolver, pois a imagem aparece normalmente nos textarea, no preview do TinyMCE do respectivo textarea e até mesmo no PDF gerado pelo TinyMCE em cada textarea. O problema é quando tenho que consolidar todos os dados de todos os textarea num único PDF. Se alguém já passou por isso ou souber como resolver......

Answer (score 0):

num forum de outro país, recebi uma sugestão: não usar o FPDF e sim imprimir a partir do print do próprio TinyMCE (mas aí o usuário teria que ter em sua máquina um drive de impressão em PDF, como cutepdf por exemplo). Para isso, a fim de imprimir os dados de todos textarea, sugeriram criar um textarea adicional, em outra página, e inserir nele os dados de todos textarea (com um echo do PHP). Não era bem a solução desejada, pois fiz os testes e demora uns 20 segundos, tanto para carregar os dados no textarea, bem como para imprimir em PDF. O tempo não foi um absurdo, mas acredito que com o aumento de dados/figuras nos textarea por cada usuário, isso possa vir a prejudicar o desempenho quando a opção for a impressão total. Compartilho isso com todos, pois o objetivo é difundir soluções, mas espero que surja alguma nova ideia, mais operacional que essa que me sugeriram acima.